How to Modify Odoo v17 Time-Off Accrual Calculation to Exclude Unpaid Leave Periods?
Problem Description
I'm working on an Odoo v17 implementation and need assistance modifying the way total annual leave accruals are calculated. Currently, the system calculates accruals based on the total employment period, but I need to exclude periods of unpaid leave from this calculation.
Desired Functionality
Exclude Unpaid Leave: The accrual calculation should subtract the days of unpaid leave from the total worked days before calculating the accrued leave.
Affect on Leave Balance: This adjustment should reflect in the employee's available leave balance.

Example:
Consider an employee "Demo User" with the following details:
Accrual Plan: 20 days per year
Employment Period: 2021-04-26 to 2024-08-27 (approximately 1220 days)
Unpaid Leave Taken: 38 days

Current Calculation (Default Odoo):
Accrued Leave: (1220 * 20) / 365 ≈ 66.85 days
Balance after Usage: If 65 days have been used, the balance would be: 66.85 - 65 = 1.85 days

Desired Calculation:
Adjusted Work Period: 1220 - 38 = 1182 days
Accrued Leave: (1182 * 20) / 365 ≈ 64.77 days
Balance after Usage: If 65 days have been used, the balance would be: 64.77 - 65 ≈ -0.23 days (or 0 days left)

Current implementation:
from odoo import api, fields, models
from datetime import timedelta
import logging

from odoo import models, fields

class HrLeaveType(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.leave.type'

    exclude_from_accural = fields.Boolean(string='Exclude From Accural', default=False,
                                     help="If checked, accural will not be counted in total accural days.")


class HolidaysAllocation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.leave.allocation'

    def _calculate_unpaid_leave_days(self, date_from, date_to):
        unpaid_leaves = self.env['hr.leave'].search([
            ('employee_id', '=', self.employee_id.id),
            ('state', '=', 'validate'),
            ('request_date_from', '>=', date_from),
            ('request_date_to', '<=', date_to),
            ('holiday_status_id.exclude_from_accural', '=', True),  # Filter types by out field
        ])
        logging.info(f"Reducing {[(x.name, x, unpaid_leaves[0].number_of_days) for x in unpaid_leaves]}")  #TODO remove
        return sum(leave.number_of_days for leave in unpaid_leaves)
   
    @api.model
    def _process_accrual_plans(self, date_to=False, force_period=False, log=True):
        res = super()._process_accrual_plans(date_to=date_to, force_period=force_period, log=log)
        
        for allocation in self:
            if allocation.accrual_plan_id:
                date_from = allocation.date_from or allocation.create_date.date()
                date_to = date_to or fields.Date.today()
                
                # Calculate total period and unpaid leave days
                total_days = (date_to - date_from).days + 1
                unpaid_days = allocation._calculate_unpaid_leave_days(date_from, date_to)
                adjusted_days = total_days - unpaid_days
                logging.info(f"{adjusted_days=} = {total_days=} - {unpaid_days=} = {adjusted_days=}")
                logging.info(f"Before adjusting: {allocation.number_of_days}") #TODO remove 
                # Adjust the number of days based on the ratio of adjusted days to total days
                allocation.number_of_days *= (adjusted_days / total_days)
                logging.info(f"After adjusting: {allocation.number_of_days}") #TODO remove 
        return res



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_hr_leave_type_form_inherit_exclude_from_accural" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.leave.type.form.inherit.accural.inclusion</field>
        <field name="model">hr.leave.type</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_holidays.edit_holiday_status_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//group[@name='configuration']" position="after">
                <group string="Accural Inclusion" name="exclude_from_accural">
                    <field name="exclude_from_accural"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

But It only works when creating hr.leave.allocation. But if I add unpaid leave on calendar it's not recalculated.
Questions
Is there a way to modify the time-off leave in to recalculate accrual each time we add unpaid leave in callendar ?

We had this issue as well and unfortunately it does work in the way we expected (neither in the way Odoo's team expects). Odoo handles it in the following way:

On the accrual plan, activate the "Based on worked time" option.
On the time off type, under the field "Kind of Time Off" set it as "Absence".

This is where the usefulness of this functionality stops.
The accrual plan runs everyday and based on the "nextcall" and "lastcall" fields on the accrual plan, it decides if it will run the accruals on this record or not. Once it is run once on a specific date, it won't run on it again even if you create an unpaid leave retroactively.
This is where the issue starts.
The accrual plan runs based on the working schedule of the employee. It first checks if there is a work entry on the "nextcall" date, if it finds it, it behaves accordingly, if it doesn't find a work entry, it assume this person was present and worked that day and will add the accruals based on his working schedule (i.e. if the day in included in the working schedule as a working day).
So to solve this issue you will need to alter the behaviour and the "nextcall" to allow it to run based on the creation date of the work entry and to avoid it 'assuming' that the employee has worked that day based on the working schedule.
